# Black screen when watching a video on Youtube

Tags: adobe

When I attempt to watch a Youtube video, on my Compaq Presario 700,  OS: Ubuntu 11.1, all I can see is a black screen.  There is no message regarding Adobe or any other thing, all I get is a black screen.

I have gone to Ubuntu Software Center and added both the Adobe plugin, and the Adobe 10.0 which is subsequently listed in the Ubuntu Software Center as Adobe 11. In both of those scenarios I have also added the add-ons they recommended. I also removed them before adding the other Adobe. I also tried adding Light Spark. None of this has resolved this.

Does anyone know of any other means or software that I can access so I can watch Youtube videos or any other videos I might want to watch?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just install chrome. It has peperflash included with allows you to watch youtube ;).

Comment: Can you post image of the problem,please?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to install Google Chrome. You don't need to worry about flash plugin or anything. Videos can be played easily.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you Flash plugin for your browser is upto date. There are a lot of software avaliable for watching youtube videos like the Minitube which can be installed from the software centre or from the terminal via `sudo apt-get install minitube`